# Excel VBA - Log changes when old value of a cell is changed manually in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add detailed log with changes to the sheet "Audit" when a cell value is changed in Sheet 1. However no changes should be logged when value is entered in a blank cell. I am working on the below code , but unable to remove blank cell change logs.

```
Option Explicit


Const LiveWS As String = "Sheet1"
Const AuditWS As String = "Audit"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Dim iRow As Integer
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim iLastRow As Long

  For iRow = 9 To 20
    For iCol = 4 To 22
      If Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> Sheets(LiveWS).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value Then
        iLastRow = Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(iLastRow + 1, 1) = "Cell(" & CStr(iRow) & "," & CStr(iCol) & ") " _
          & "changed from '" & Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value & "' " _
          & "to '" & Sheets(LiveWS).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value & "'"
        Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Sheets(LiveWS).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
      End If
    Next iCol
  Next iRow

  iLastRow = Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets(AuditWS).Cells(iLastRow + 1, 1) = "Workbook opened by " & Environ("USERNAME") _
     & " on " & Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " at " & Format(Now(), "hh:nn:ss")

  ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: You are checking on every opening if each cell in Audit's (9, 4) to (20, 22) range is equal in value to the corresponding cell in Sheet1. If not, you write Audit's value and Sheet1's value and the address of that cell. Correct? That's what you want to do? OK for the blank check, but your code needs bigger changes i think. if User1 changes stuff, then User 2 opens and closes the sheet 3 times, then user 1 comes back and doesn't change anything, it will log all of this as 'changes' because the value still will be different.

Comment: Yes, but this issue is secondary. i think that line of code can be removed. Please help with the blank check issue.

Answer (score 1):

You sheet events to track changes.
behind your `sheet1` try something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public bLog     As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If bLog Then
        ''''' YOUR Logging code here or a call to logging routine
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   bLog = Not IsEmpty(Target.Value2)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what needs to be worked with! I would ALSO add a public string that takes in the value of current selection. that way if there is a change, you can have a proper before and after!

Comment: agreed. having the old value before change is critical for logging.

Comment: Careful: this will only work if you select one cell at a time. If you (intentionally or accidentally) select more than one cell and for example press the delete key, then...

Comment: Good observation @stenci. To take this in consideration, there could ba a log of the range being selected as well. Put the selection's address in a public string, and if there is a change, note the entire range. That way only the active cell will be displayed but you know the whole range was in fact changed (to the same value, presumably... but maybe not in the case of a formula being dragged).

Comment: valid point. but you need to understand the capacity and limitation of excel ( and vba).  One can use range undo/redo, clipboard, win messages for a bullet proof logger. But then again that's always a overkill in VBA, if that sort of extensive features are required using some other language is more  efficient and advised.

Comment: Should i add like this ?